# ¿Es posible modificar el objeto console para añadirle un método personalizado?

Tags: método, objeto, diálogo, prototipos

Me gustaría crear un "console.test()", un método que solo haga console.log() si la variable test == true. Pero creo que no es posible utilizar protoype para crear dicho método. Estoy un poco verde en esto, ¿alguien puede aportar algo de luz?

Otra duda que me surge es: ¿Porque en un console.log podemos introducir información separada por comas? ¿Podría simular algo así?

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien, quieres usar un objeto que herede de console y crear un método llamado test que haga lo mismo que console.log pero sólo si la variable de control que comentas es true.

Es bastante sencillo de la siguiente manera:

```
var debugMode = true;

(function() {
    var exLog = console.log;
    console.test = function(msg) {
        if (debugMode)
            exLog.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})()
```

De esta manera tienes el método console.log nativo de JS que se seguirá comportando como siempre y además tu nuevo método console.test que dejará de lanzar mensajes en la consola en el momento en el que la variable de control debugMode sea false.

https://jsfiddle.net/wLpgxs24/20/

La idea es bastante útil ya que por ejemplo a la hora de pasar de desarrollo a producción, sería tan sencillo como poner la variable global de control debugMode a false, evitando de esta manera tener que ir buscando cada console.log para comentarlo o borrarlo.

En cuanto a la otra pregunta, sí, console.log admite varios parámetros:

- console.log(msg). El que se suele usar de manera más habitual.
  Muestra un mensaje.
- console.log(obj1, obj2, .... , objN).En este caso se mostrarán las
  representaciones en cadena de cada uno de los objetos pasados como
  parámetro.

Answer (score 1):

He mirado por internet porque tu pregunta me ha generado interes, mira a ver si esto te sirve:

```
       console.test = function(/**/) {
            var args = arguments;
            for(var i=0; i<args.length; i++){
                alert(args[i]);
            }
        };
        console.test("hola que tal", "pepe");
```

Lo de los parámetros infinitos lo he sacado de este hilo, lo paso por si quieres mirartelo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338291/javascript-infinite-parameters-for-function

Por cierto no he puesto lo que dices de test === true, porque nose bien como tienes montado eso, pasa código y si puedo te ayudo en algo.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente, tienes que condicionar la definición de `console.test` al valor de `window.test`

```
window.test = true // o false

if(window.test === true) {
  console.test = function() { /* hace algo */ };
} else {
  console.test=function() { /* no hace nada */ };
}
```

**Lo más simple**, sería hacer:

```
window.test = true // o false

if(window.test === true) {
  console.test = console.log;
} else {
  console.test=function() { /* no hace nada */ };
}
```

Pero para definir `console.test` hay muchas maneras y vamos a explorarlas para que la respuesta sea lo más completa posible:

## Llamando la función "a lo bruto"

```
console.test = function() {  
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);  
  console.log(args); 
};
```

Pero esto imprimirá los argumentos dentro de un array:

```
console.test('hola','amigo')

// imprime ["hola", "amigo"]
```

---

## Usando spread operator

En navegadores modernos, el  `spread operator` se encarga de pasar el array de argumentos como parámetros

```
console.test = function() {  console.log(...arguments); };

console.test('hola',{a:1}, 'amigo')

// imprime hola, ▸{a:1}, amigo
```

---

## Usando `console.log.apply`

Puedes hacer algo como:

```
window.test = true // o false

if (window.test === true) {
   console.test = function() {  console.log.apply(console,arguments)         };
} else {
   console.test = function() { /* no hace nada */   };
}
```

Al usar `Function.prototype.apply` puedes llamar a una función con su respectivo contexto (en este caso `console`) y pasarle N argumentos en forma de array:

```
 console.log.apply(console,['a','b','c']);
```

Que a su vez invocarán a la función con ese array en forma de una lista de argumentos, lo cual equivale a hacer:

```
 console.log('a','b','c');
```

**PEEEERO** todos estos enfoques harán que en el inspector de tu consola todos los `console.test` **aparezcan siendo llamados desde el script donde definiste la función**, cuando sería más útil que aparecieran llamados desde el script (y la línea) donde lo hayas invocado.

---

## Usando `Function.prototype.bind`

Para que los llamados a `console.test` aparezcan invocados desde el script y la línea correcta, lo que se hace es:

```
window.test = true // o false

if (window.test === true) {
   console.test = console.log.bind(console);
} else {
   console.test = function() { /* no hace nada */   };
}
```

Al usar `Function.prototype.bind` estás en el fondo haciendo un duplicado de la función, que sería equivalente a hacer `console.test = console.log` y aparecerá siendo llamado desde el script que lo invoca. Pero **además**, la gracia del bind, es que puedes pasarle parámetros adicionales que se anteponen a los argumentos:

```
console.test = console.log.bind(console,'TEST:');
```

En cuyo caso `console.test('hola',{x:1},'amigo');` imprimirá

```
TEST: hola ▸{a: 1} amigo
```

Puedes ir más allá y hacer que `TEST` se imprima con un color:

```
console.test = console.log.bind(console, '%cTEST:', 'color:#090;font-weight:bold;');
```

En cuyo caso `TEST:` tendrá un color distinto. Abre el panel devtools usando F12 y corre este script:

```js
console.test = console.log.bind(console, '%cTEST:', 'color:#090;font-weight:bold;');

console.test('hola',{a:1},'chao');
```

(va a alegar que el snippet está "sandboxed" pero igual aparecerá TEST en verde)

---

## Usando `getters` (este es mi preferido)

Podrías definir un método en el objeto `console` con parámetros dinámicos. Por ejemplo, que imprimiera el tiempo que ha pasado desde que declaraste `console.test` hasta que lo invocas. De nuevo, abre tu panel con F12 y ejecuta:

```js
window.test = true;
window.timeStart = Date.now();

Object.defineProperty(console, "test", {
  get: function() {
    if (window.test !== true) {
      return function() { /* no hace nada */ };
    }
    return Function.prototype.bind.call(
      console.log,
      console,
      '%c' + parseInt((Date.now() - window.timeStart) / 100, 10) / 10 + 's TEST:',
      "color:#03C;font-weight:bold;"
    );
  }
});

window.setTimeout(function() {
  console.test('Me imprimo a los 2 segundos');
}, 2000);

window.setTimeout(function() {
  console.test('Me imprimo a los 3.5 segundos');
}, 3500);
```

La consola dirá:

```
2s TEST: Me imprimo a los 2 segundos
3.5s TEST: Me imprimo a los 3.5 segundos
```

Y eso es algo que no podrías hacer con `console.log.bind` directamente.

[Ve un ejemplo corriendo en Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zl2tWqrP7yrub3omAOhl?p=preview) (primero abre la consola con F12 para ver los mensajes)